# (to place) intent and end

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've just encountered the following phrase: "he has placed intent and end over this claim". "Intent and end" or "to place intent and end" sounds like an idiom but I couldn't find it in any dictionary. What should that phrase mean?

Comment: Never heard that phrase.  And what you intend to say with it is unclear.  What is a "claim" in this context?

Comment: It would help if you told us where you encountered it and the subject matter. Do you have a link to the text?

Comment: Would you be okay with making, the end of the phrase " he has placed intent and end over this claim" more specific and self explanatory so we know what we're getting ourselves into by answering.

Comment: "Debates on the matter of lying were held all over the Christian world till John Cassian the Roman has placed intent and end over the claim that any lie were sinful".

Comment: Do you have a reference for that???

Comment: Sounds like originally there was a statement ("claim") that was used in debates, and that John Cassian elevated the importance of (1) intent and (2) end (i.e. result, impact) above the significance of a prior claim that all untruths are morally wrong. But as to what that actually *means*....

Comment: The quotation "Debates on the matter of lying were held all over the Christian world till John Cassian the Roman has placed intent and end over the claim that any lie were sinful" would not appear in any properly edited publication—even if "place intent and end over" were an idiomatic phrase, which it's not—because "has placed" should be simply "placed," and "any lie were" should be "any lie was." Wherever the poster's encounter with this sentence occurred, I strongly suspect that it wasn't in a published piece of writing.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent idiommatic phrase, still common now, is "for (or to) all intents and purposes", which means

> to (for) all intents and purposes (less usually to all intents): in regard to any end or object, for all practical purposes, ‘practically’.

(From [OED Online](http://oed.com/).)

The phrase was somewhat common in the singular, "intent and purpose", and had the variant form "intent and end", in centuries past. The meaning should be clear if "purpose" is understood for "end". So, this is found in *The Travels of Sir John Mandeville* (1725 text):

> Wherefore I will hold me still, without
>   any more rehearsing of diversities or of marvels that be beyond, to that
>   *intent and end*, that whoso will go into those countries, he shall find
>   enough to speak of, that I have not touched of in no wise.

The singular and variant form with "end" is still to be encountered in the wild:

> The issue here isn't that the Church does this - it is common practice in traditionally Orthodoxy countries re homosexuality and long-time partnerships - it is what the *intent and end* of this economia is: to bring a sinner to repentance in time, or to slowly change the Church until it sees this is no sin.

(From a comment dated Nov. 14, 2014, on the "Statement of the Brotherhood of the Orthodox Clergy Association of Houston and Southeast Texas on the Comments of Fr. Robert Arida on Homosexuality" included in a blog post titled ["Texas Orthodox Clergy Deliver Stinging Rebuke to Fr. Arida and Enablers"](http://www.monomakhos.com/texas-orthodox-clergy-deliver-stinging-rebuke-to-arida-and-enablers/).)